# ID is not autoincrementing in my sqlite3 database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am trying to build a GUI CRUD app in python where a user enters an object; say an apple the amount of objects (10) and the date at which they conducted their research could be today or yesterday etc (29/03/2021) in this format.

This data then gets sent to a sqlite3 database so reports can be run.
When implementing and the python file the sqlite database contains all the information added bar the ID which should be autoincremented, instead it shows NULL.

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS errors (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
        Subject text, Total integer, Date text)")
        self.conn.commit()

    def insert(self, subject, total, date):
        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO errors VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)", (subject, total, date))
        self.conn.commit()
```

So basically my ID column is not incrementing and is saying NULL. I have tried removing "AUTOINCREMENT" aswell as some say it is not necessary with PRIMARY KEY PRESENT but still doesn't work.

Comment: Delete the table and rerun.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` is always a red flag. I bet there's an older version of the table with a different definition.

Comment: Make sure you read and understand https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html and the implications of `AUTOINCREMENT` before deciding to use it or not. Don't just blindly parrot what other people do.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, autoincrement ids only works when sqlite is creating the value. Here you're giving it `NULL` explicitely so it does as you ask and uses `NULL`.

If you want the default behaviour, just don't provide a value for that column:

```sql
insert into errors (subject, total, date) values (?, ?, ?)
```

unlike postgres, sqlite apparently doesn't support DEFAULT pseudo-expressions, so that seems to not be an option.

Incidentally, the `AUTOINCREMENT` is probably why sqlite doesn't error on `NULL`:

> According to the SQL standard, PRIMARY KEY should always imply NOT NULL. Unfortunately, due to a bug in some early versions, this is not the case in SQLite. Unless the column is an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY or the table is a WITHOUT ROWID table or the column is declared NOT NULL, SQLite allows NULL values in a PRIMARY KEY column.

meaning a column which is strictly declared as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` *should* implicitly reject NULL values, as it will make the column an alias / replacement for the implicit ROWID.

Comment: I suspected the same thing with the `NULL` primary key but I actually set up an `SQLite` DB with the same code and autoincrement works! Maybe it's a "version thing"? Also, I don't think using `NULL` as the column name is equivalent to inserting `NULL` into the `id` column. Just wanted to point this out

Comment: @Masklinn. An Operational error gets flared up when getting rid of NULL as there are 4 columns "but only 3 values were supplied" I originally thought the NULL parameter would simply be a placeholder and the default behavior would take over but seems not... Interesting info on SQLite and NULL values.

Comment: Inserting null into an IPK column will cause sqlite to automatically generate a number.

Comment: If the column is defined as `ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` it does not allow nulls

Comment: @danidee they're not using null as column name, they're using null as a value. If it were a column name it would be *before* the `values` keyword.

Comment: @conman00 please read the code I provided. I specify the columns to insert values into explicitely, meaning sqlite will fall back to the default behaviour for all others. Because you don't provide column names, you have to provide values for each column, and can't fall back to defaults.